# Comment-flag options have gotten much more compact; could we have a little more breathing room?

Tags: feature-request, flags, design

Flagging a comment produces the following initial interface (multiple sites, and confirmed with other users):

[image: flag options]

Before today the options weren't quite so *cozy*; a couple times I've had to take more than one try at getting the right one, and I haven't even tried on my tablet yet (where my fingers are bigger than a mouse cursor).  Could we possibly spread these out a bit more?

You might also notice the absence of the button, which becomes available only after selecting an option.  I *think* it used to be present but grayed out.  If this isn't part of a broader redesign where we don't show buttons at all until they're active, you might want to change that too.

Comment: For comparison, [this is what the dialog looks like in a tab I'd had open for a few days](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lAeuP.png). Indeed there's more space between lines and the button is grayed out.

Comment: @Gilles The "invisible" flag button only happens on a few sites (and that bug has existed since the end of February :(): http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3968/the-close-dialog-is-missing-the-close-button-until-a-reason-is-chosen.

Comment: Only now, when seeing this on a large, high-quality monitor, did I notice the faint outline where the button should be.  I thought it was totally absent, not just cloaking!  (Also, confirmed that this doesn't happen on all my sites; I just got unlucky in taking the screen shot.  My focus really is on the layout of the options.)